# Failed to create Component 'PayFee' when I drag the user control to the Main Form

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am using a class PayFeeClass to connect the user control the database and then call that class in UserControl (i.e "PayFee.cs") but it's throwing an error:

[image]

This is my code for "PayFee.cs"

```
using SSC_LIBRARY.Classes;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SSC_LIBRARY
{

public partial class PayFee : UserControl
{


    public PayFee()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
        PayFeeClass pfc = new PayFeeClass();

    public void Clear()
    {
        t1.Text = "";
        t2.Text = "";
        t3.Text = "";
        t4.Text = "";
        t5.Text = "";
        t6.Text = "";

    }
    private void PayFee_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void B2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pfc.Fee_ID = t1.Text;
        pfc.Student_ID = t2.Text;
        pfc.ChallanNo = t3.Text;
        pfc.Amount = t4.Text;
        pfc.Due_date = t5.Value.Date;
        pfc.Fee_type = t6.selectedValue;

        bool success = pfc.Insert(pfc);
        if (success == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted");
            Clear();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Record not Added. Try again!");
        }
    }

    private void t6_onItemSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

And this is my Code for PayFeeClass:

```
using System;using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace SSC_LIBRARY.Classes
{
class PayFeeClass
{
    public string Fee_ID { get; set; }
    public string Student_ID { get; set; }
    public string ChallanNo { get; set; }
    public string Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Due_date { get; set; }
    public string Fee_type { get; set; }

    static string myconnstr = 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString;

    public DataTable Select()
    {
        //Step1: Database connection
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myconnstr);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            //Step2: Writing SQL Query
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM fee";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            conn.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
    public bool Insert(PayFeeClass pfc)
    {
        bool isSuccess = false;
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myconnstr);
        try
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO fee  (Fee_ID, Student_ID, ChallanNo, 
Amount, Due_date, Fee_type) VALUES (@Fee_ID, @Student_ID, @ChallanNo, 
@Amount, @Due_date, @Fee_type)";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fee_ID", pfc.Fee_ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Student_ID", pfc.Student_ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChallanNo", pfc.ChallanNo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", pfc.Amount);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Due_date", pfc.Due_date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fee_type", pfc.Fee_type);


            conn.Open();
            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rows > 0)
            {
                isSuccess = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isSuccess = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return isSuccess;

    }
}
}
```

But when I drag the user control to the main form, it gives the error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The exception is being raised due to, the following line in PayFeeClass.cs:

```
static string myconnstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString;
```

The ConnectionStrings section of the app.config that Visual Studio uses (note, not the one your application uses) 
does not have a connection string entry for `connstr`

You have two options for fixing this:
First option, move the line that sets up the connection string property in to a separate `Initialise` function that you call from your Form class.

Second option is to check if the UserControl is in DesignMode.

Put this in your controls Constructor to only retrieve the Connection String at run time and not design time.

```
bool isDesignMode = (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) || DesignMode;

if (!isDesignMode)
{
    myconnstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: But where do I paste the code you provided?
because I tied it it but it now gives different errors!

Comment: @HamzaKhan Put this in your controls Constructor to only retrieve the Connection String at run time and not design time